# Pandas Dataframe from NumPy array - incorrect datatypes and can't change

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, describe

I am trying to sort the following Pandas DataFrame in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

heading_cols = [
"Video Title",
    "Up Ratings",
    "Down Ratings",
    "Views",
    "User Name",
    "Subscribers",
]
column_1 = [
    "Adelaide",
    "Brisbane",
    "Darwin",
    "Hobart",
    "Sydney",
    "Melbourne",
    "Perth",
]
column_2 = [1295, 5905, 112, 1357, 2058, 1566, 5386]
column_3 = [1158259, 1857594, 120900, 205556, 4336374, 3806092, 1554769]
column_4 = [600.5, 1146.4, 1714.7, 619.5, 1214.8, 646.9, 869.4]
column_5 = ["Bob","Tom","Dave","Sally","Rick","Mary","Roberta"]
column_6 = [25000,30000,15000,15005,20000,31111,11000]

#Generate data:
xdata_arr = np.array([column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4,column_5,column_6]).T

# Generate the DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(xdata_arr, columns=heading_cols)
print(df)
```

The next 2 lines of code are causing problems:

```
# Print DataFrame and basic stats:
print(df["Up Ratings"].describe())
print(df.sort('Views', ascending=False))
```

Problems:

- The sorting is not working for any column.
- The statistics should include things like mean, std, min, max, etc. These do not show up.

The problem is that dtypes() is returning "object" for all the columns. This is wrong. some should be integers, but I can't figure out how to change only the numeric ones. I have tried:

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

but this is not working. So, then I went to the NumPy array and tried to change the dtypes there:

```
dt = np.dtype(
[
    (heading_cols[0], np.str_),
    (heading_cols[1], np.int16),
    (heading_cols[2], np.int16),
    (heading_cols[3], np.int16),
    (heading_cols[4], np.str_),
    (heading_cols[5], np.int16),
]
```

)

but this does not work either.

Is there a way to manually change the dtype to numeric?

Comment: ``convert_object()`` like most pandas methods returns a NEW object, do: ``df = df.convert_object(convert_numeric=True)``

Comment: Ok, I just tried that, but I am getting this message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\testing.py", line 23, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame(xdata_arr,columns=heading_cols).convert_object(convert_numeric=True)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1843, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'convert_object'

Comment: typo: ``convert_objects``

Comment: Sorry, I just saw it too. Thanks. It works.

Comment: note that the point of ``convert_numeric=True`` is that will set numeric to their value, and ANY other objects to ``NaN``), so it will 'forcibly' clean up the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most methods in pandas, `convert_objects` returns a NEW object.

```
In [20]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
Out[20]: 
  Video Title  Up Ratings  Down Ratings   Views User Name  Subscribers
0    Adelaide        1295       1158259   600.5       Bob        25000
1    Brisbane        5905       1857594  1146.4       Tom        30000
2      Darwin         112        120900  1714.7      Dave        15000
3      Hobart        1357        205556   619.5     Sally        15005
4      Sydney        2058       4336374  1214.8      Rick        20000
5   Melbourne        1566       3806092   646.9      Mary        31111
6       Perth        5386       1554769   869.4   Roberta        11000

In [21]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes
Out[21]: 
Video Title      object
Up Ratings        int64
Down Ratings      int64
Views           float64
User Name        object
Subscribers       int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you did, I could have done the whole thing in one line - create the dataframe and simultaneously make the conversion. More importantly, I was not aware of the "return new object" part. In order to bypass that, why can't I use "inplace = True" as here: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True, inplace=True)? <---I tried this and I get an error message.

Comment: yeh, ``convert_objects`` doesn't have an inplace, and I am a big -1 on just not using them in general. They are not intuitve for a reader and rarely provide a perf benefit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All questions here are answered.